# Netbios name resolution fails intermittently in mixed environment

Tags: windows-7, networking, mac, printer

I'm hoping for some tips and suggestions for resolving some issues I've run into connecting to our shared printer.

I have a network with a network attached storage box, a windows 10 workstation, two windows 7 workstations, and two macs running 10.9.

I've had intermittent problems getting all of the systems to browse the network and one of the macs continues to be unable to see anything without me specifying an IP address.  While the macs can work with the NAS using an IP address they're unable to work with the windows 10 workstation sharing the printer connected by USB.

All of the windows pcs, the nas, and the Epson printer now inter-operate, but the Macs are unable to print.  One simply never sees it, or anything else when browsing, the other will show and setup the printer, and claim it's printing (print job smoothly exits the print queue), but never prints anything and never generates an error.

I have a router providing DHCP.  DNS services are provided by my ISP.  I am not running a server.  I'm unable to add additional systems to our network, so if you have solutions that don't require adding a new system I would greatly appreciate your input.  I'd like to be able to browse from the Macs as well.

When pinging from the macs they are unable to ping to the netbios names of any systems, but can ping by ip address.  All of the windows systems can ping by netbios name and ip address.  No firewalls are present, other than on the router.  All windows systems have network discovery turned on.

Comment: does the DNS server resolve internal names or just proxy to the external DNS providers? do you have any WINS servers deployed on any of the windows boxs?